# getopt to take only one argument

Tags: c, getopt

I have a question about `getopt` in C. I have multiple option flags and am trying to get it to take one argument for everything. The command line will look something like `command -a fileName` or `command -b fileName` or `command -ab fileName`. Basically every command takes in one fileName and if they want to combine commands they should only have to type in one fileName. In getopt the string looks like `a:b:` and a variable is set to `argv[argc -1]`. This is fine if it's just one option but fails if there are multiple options (ie `command -ab fileName`) since `:` forces users to input an option but `::` will make the singe options not force the user to type in an option. Any suggestions?

Comment: According to the `getopt` docs: "A colon ( ':' ) shall be returned if getopt() detects a missing argument and the first character of optstring was a colon ( ':' )."  So, maybe pass `:a:b:` to getopt.

Comment: Perhaps you should have a specific flag to attach the filename to, rather than overloading the other args. For example, `getopt(argc, argv, "f:abcde")`.

Comment: Is the filename really a parameter of the options, rather than just the argument to the command? Can you write `command filename` with no options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `optind` global variable lets you know how many of the `argv` strings were used. So one way to approach this problem is to just drop the colons, and use a string like "ab".
Here's an example of what the code looks like (adapted from the example in the man page):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "ab")) != -1)
    {
        if (ch == 'a')
            printf("Got A\n");
        else if (ch == 'b')
            printf("Got B\n");
        else
            printf("Got confused\n");
    }

    if (optind != argc-1) 
        printf("You forgot to enter the filename\n");
    else
        printf("File: %s\n", argv[optind]);
}
```

If you run this with a command line like

```
./test -ab hello
```

the output is

```
Got A
Got B
File: hello
```